# Single exe for Flutter Windows

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows

I'm currently building a windows application using flutter technology and after the presentation of the app my client is requesting for a single exe file for deployment. While doing some research I've stumble upon several post on GitHub but it's being tagged as duplicate to this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/75200. The thread has been years ago since it's posted so I was wondering if there's someone who already made a step to achieve this.

As doing a deep dive in flutter I've noticed that they are using CMake for compiling, I'm not familiar with c++, CMake or ninja.build

Any help is appreciated.

Thankyou

Comment: You can use a setup installer software to build a single executable/installer file. Softwares like Inno Setup can do the job. A reference for you https://protocoderspoint.com/how-to-create-exe-installation-file-of-flutter-windows-application/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now, Found a third party app for this, its called Enigma Virtual Box..
This will package every files to single exe. NOT INSTALLER

Tutorial from yt: youtube.com/watch?v=LEk2Ry5ERZQ&t=93s

Tested output files from both local and virtualBox

Comment: Downloaded it through chocolatey, this is the perfect solution and it's free! I wish flutter could do this natively.